# Select certain properties on ::with

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a members table with a lot of data. I want to view a list of "Alarms" with the member's name included, but no other information about that member.

I am currently using

```
Alarm::with('member')->get();
```

which returns all the alarm data *and* all the member data associated with member_id.

What I want is to specify the "member" data to only return "name" and nothing else from member.

This could normally be done with

```
Member::select('name')->get();
```

but I'd like to know how to achieve that result through eager loading **without having to edit the model** and add to the "hidden" since I'll be needing the data in other calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alarm::with(['member' => function ($q) {
  $q->select('id', 'name');
}])->get();
```

A few things to consider:

1. `select` won't work for `belongsToMany` (many-to-many) relation like above, since it's bugged.
2. You need to select `primary key` / `foreign key` (depending on the relation) in order to let Eloquent match related models to their respective parents
3. If you want to output data through some kind of JSON api, I suggest using transformers instead - for example [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/)